# Material Transitions in pre lollipop apps

Tags: android, android-activity, material-design, android-transitions

I am trying to use the transitions which introduced in material design in pre - lollipop apps(Min API19). I was going through http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/meaningful-transitions.html#meaningful-transitions-visual-continuity transitions. But couldn't find how to do these transition mainly the second one on click of list item it expands the details. Can anybody help me to do this.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there exists any special way to do this on any of the platform version. You have to do transition animations yourself. Although, we can make use of new animator framework, and some features from the design library.

Comment: Its called as Shared element transition .Please go through these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339690/shared-element-transition-dont-have-the-expected-behaviour   https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Comment: thanks.. @Subin Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the "`Material transitions`" (or shared content animations) in pre-Lollipop versions, whether you're using ***Appcompat*** or not.

Check this link [Custom animations](http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html)